# Checking whether two algebras are isomorphic with MAGMA

Tags: representation-theory, computer-algebra-systems, magma-cas

I want to use MAGMA to check whether to given finite dimensional algebras over a field are isomorphic.
Here my attempt:

```
K := RationalField();
A<x,y> := FPAlgebra<K, x,y |
      x^2,y^2,(x+y)^2>;
A;

B<x,y> := FPAlgebra<K, x,y |
      x*y,y*(x+y),(x+y)*x>;
B;
IsIsomorphic(A,B);
```

It gives the error: Runtime error in 'IsIsomorphic': Bad argument types
Argument types given: AlgFP, AlgFP in the online magma calculator http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/ .

> Question: Is there an easy fix to this? How can one check whether the two algebras are isomorphic using MAGMA?

Comment: In case you didn't see it yet: the two ideals are easily checked to be equal, so the algebras are isomorphic.

Comment: Just to tell you why this doesn't work. Magma does not like trying isomorphisms of finitely presented objects, because there is no such algorithm (it's undecidable). It can do it for finite stuff, like finite groups, so if you ever want to do something like this, you need to (usually) have finite objects.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Replacing the rationals with a finite field also seems to not work.

Comment: You don't have a finite object. You have a finitely presented object. You might know it's finite, but there is no algorithm to determine if a finitely presented algebra is finite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For finite fields you could do this:

```
f:=GF(31);
FA<e1,x,y>:=FreeAlgebra(f,3);
rrr:=[x*x,y*y,(x+y)*(x+y)];
A:=BasicAlgebra(FA,rrr,1,[<1,1>,<1,1>]);
A;
```

Basic algebra of dimension 4 over GF(31)

Number of projective modules: 1

Number of generators: 3

```
FB<e,a,b>:=FreeAlgebra(f,3);
RRR:=[a*b,b*(a+b),(a+b)*a];
B:=BasicAlgebra(FB,RRR,1,[<1,1>,<1,1>]);
B;
```

Basic algebra of dimension 4 over GF(31)

Number of projective modules: 1

Number of generators: 3

```
IsIsomorphic(A,B);
```

false
[ 0]

I don't know if it is implemented for infinite fields. I get an error message when I enter it with f:=RationalField();